# Rails - execute task before server starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want my app to execute a task (download CSV files from another website & parse them) just before the server starts.

In which file exactly should I put the code for this?(maybe `db/seeds.rb`?)

Also, any idea on how to test this with RSpec?

Comment: Why not use `initializers`

Answer (score 5):

The `initializers` folder is the proper place to set this tasks.

Just create a file with `.rb` extension, and everything else will be performed on start.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initializers

Answer (score 2):

From the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#running-code-before-rails):

> In the rare event that your application needs to run some code before Rails itself is loaded, put it above the call to require 'rails/all' in config/application.rb.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `initializers` folder, can create any `.rb` file and can write any logical code in that file. It will be executed on start.

*But it may slow down server start, because in your case csv download and parsing may take time to execute.*

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#running-code-before-rails

Answer (score 0):

One solution, this may be not right

in lib/tasks/say_hello_rake.rake

```
namespace :sample do
  task :your_task_name do
    puts 'Hello my task ... '
  end
end
```

before rails s

rake sample:your_task_name